# List all nginx sites from config

Tags: php, parsing, nginx

While writing `php` script I need to list all nginx sites (vhosts) that's are set up on webserver, with ports and flag if the specific vhost is sll-enabled.

I can do run and then parse `nginx -t` output. At first, I tried to use regexps, but the problem is, nginx can use different formated config, so this can be like this

```
server {
  server_name blah;
  listen 433 http2 ssl;
...
}
```

or like this

```
server { server_name blah; listen 433 http2 ssl; root /siteroot1; listen 80; location / { ... } }
```

so it is a problem that pareser won't be fooled with some extra whitespaces or inline blocks.

Another approach is to walk chars one by one and implement it with number of `strpos` checks. Again, it may be formating-sensitive.

May there be any ready to use solution? Or maybe some another nginx command like args that make it list vhosts/ports only?

Thank you!

Comment: There are several tools that do this for you, i.e., converting the NGINX config to a format more easily to parse. Maybe have a look at [Crossplane/python](https://github.com/nginxinc/crossplane) or at [nginx-conf PHP](https://github.com/jakoch/nginx-conf)

Comment: @Kryptur Thank you, will give it a try. By the way, these are full config parse attempts, a bit overkill for my case, but hope it'll work!

Comment: The SSL port is 443, not 433.

Answer (score 2):

This approach works for me: `nginx -T 2>/dev/null | grep "server_name " | awk '{print $2}'`

But it depend on your configs structure. But anyway this construction: `nginx -T 2>/dev/null | grep "server_name "` should give you list of all server_names.